# ¿Cómo me conecto desde el host a un server creado en una máquina virtual?

Tags: ubuntu, servidor, virtualbox

Necesito probar una conexión entre el host (ubuntu) y una vm (ubuntu) creada con virtualbox.

En la vm, hice un server.c, el cual levanta un servidor en el puerto 9034.
Lo que quiero hacer es conectarme desde el host, al servidor levantado en la vm, usando telnet.

Puedo conectarme con ssh a la vm, ya que configuré los puertos. La vm usa adaptador NAT.

¿Alguien sabe como puedo hacer esto?

Comment: Para poder conectarse desde el host a la vm, deben estar en la misma red, para esto debes cambiar el tipo de connectión de NAT a Only-Host, esto te crea una subred entre el equipo y la maquina virtual o las maquinas virtuales que tengan la misma interface de red, ó cambias a Bridge lo cual coloca la vm en la misma red del host, es decir te da una ip directamente del router. en los dos casos debes habilitar el puerto en los firewall del vm

Answer (score 0):

Telnet es una herramienta para conectarse a un servidor a un puerto especifico de un servicio determinado:

> $telnet   ip_maquina puerto

Ejemplo:
$telnet 192.168.15.174 25
Esto realiza una conexión al servidor 192.168.15.174 al puerto 25 en el que generalmente esta el servicio de SMTP (correo electronico)

Realizar una conexión SSH es realizar una conexión al puerto 22

El servicio Telnet (puerto 23) es "algo" inseguro... lo mismo que el FTP (pueto 21) pero lo puedes habilitar para ciertas IPs..

Dependiendo de tu Linux, una manera fácil es instalar xinetd.
En tu caso (Ubuntu) desde la consola y como root:
**# apt-get install xinetd**
Luego editamos el fichero:
**/etc/xinetd.d/telnet** (con vi/nano/etc)
Y tenemos que dejar la linea:
**disable = NO**

luego reiniciamos el servicio de xinetd:

## service xinetd restart

---

Si lo queremos "asegurar" para que solo permita conexiones desde IPs especificas pondremos en el fichero:
**only_from = nuestra_IP**
(y luego de nuevo reiniciar el servicio)

Ahora ya puedes comprobar que llegas desde el otro equipo con:
$ telnet servidor 23